# D3 x-axis for each day of the week

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a JSON array like the following:

```
[
  {
    "day": "Monday",
    "sales": 242
  },
  {
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "sales": 256
  },
  ...
]
```

This data covers one week, so there is an object for each day Monday through Sunday.

I have built a bar graph with D3 with a bar for each day of the week. I am now attempting to add an x-axis with a tick label for each day.

[image]

I've done the following to set up my y-axis:

```
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.sales;
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
  .ticks(5);

svg.append("g")
  .call(yAxis);
```

This works great, but for some reason, I am stumped on how to setup my x-axis with each day of the week under the corresponding bar. Note: I am using D3 version 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your `days` are just strings, you can use `scaleBand` instead of `scaleTime`:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.day}))
    .range([0, width])//you can use rangeRound instead
    .paddingInner(someValue);//the value of the inner padding, if any.
```

Then, set the x axis accordingly:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
```

Check this snippet:

```js
var width = 550, height = 200;

var data = [{day:"Monday"},
    {day:"Tuesday"},
    {day:"Wednesday"},
    {day:"Thursday"},
    {day:"Friday"},
    {day:"Saturday"},
    {day:"Sunday"}
];

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height);
 
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.day}))
    .range([0, width*0.95])
 
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .ticks(7);

svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0,100)")
 .call(xAxis);
```

```css
text { font-size: 12px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```